# D3.js - did the transition behavior changed in v4 ?

Tags: d3.js

I have been trying to implement change animation with Mike Bostock’s General Update Pattern III ( https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234 ) 
My code seems to work with D3v3. But with D3v4 it seems to delay the transitions.

Demo (v3): https://codepen.io/_wad1m/pen/BwewKg

Same Demo (v4): https://codepen.io/_wad1m/pen/VMOrxe

Code:

```
  // JOIN new data with old elements.
  var rects = layer1.selectAll('rect')
    .data( data, function(d) { return d.id; } );

  // EXIT old elements not present in new data.
  var removeElements = rects.exit();

  removeElements
    .attr("class", "remove")
    .transition(t)
      .attr('y', 300 )
      .attr('fill-opacity', 0 )
      .remove();

  // UPDATE old elements present in new data.
  var oldElements = rects.attr("class", "old")
    .transition(t)
      .attr('x', (d,i)=> i * barWidth );

  oldElements.filter(function(d,i,arr) 
  {
    var currentHeight = d3.select(this).attr('height');
    var newHeight = calcHeight( d );
    return Math.abs( currentHeight - newHeight ) > 0.1;
  } )
  .attr('class', 'change')
  .transition(t_quick)
      .attr('height', (d)=> (d.value/8)*300 )
      .attr('y', (d)=> 300-(d.value/8)*300 );

  // ENTER new elements present in new data.
  rects.enter().append('rect')  
    .attr("class", "new") 
    .attr('x', (d,i)=> i * barWidth )
    .attr('width', barWidth-2 )
    .attr('height', calcHeight )

    .attr('y', -300 )
    .attr('fill-opacity', 0 )
  .transition(t)
    .attr('y', (d)=> 300-(d.value/8)*300 )
    .attr('fill-opacity', 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **version 3** usage doesn't look valid.  You are calling `.transition` and passing in an existing transition.  This was added in version 4; from the CHANGE.md:

> The selection.transition method now takes an optional transition instance which can be used to synchronize a new transition with an existing transition.

So, the delay you see is the expected behavior with version 4.  To make it work like your version 3, don't pass the transition in....